# Can we claim that $f(x)$ is an increasing function and its stationary point is $x = \infty$ (in this specific case)?

Tags: functions, derivatives, convex-analysis

If $f(x)$ is concave and its first derivative $f'(x) \rightarrow 0$ when $x\rightarrow \infty$, can we claim that $f(x)$ is an increasing function and its (only) stationary point is $x = \infty$ ? ( we can add this condition $f(x)\le f(\infty)$ but I am not sure about it).

Comment: If by $f(\infty)$ you mean $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$, then this limit is not guaranteed to exist. So you are right not to be sure about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. 
If a function is (strictly) concave, its derivative is (strictly) decreasing. So if in some point the derivative is zero it would become negative on the right of that point, and hence cannot go to zero at $+\infty$.